# Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardReader'

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-8.1, smartcard

I am trying to build a Windows Form application targeting Windows 7 users. 
My project uses [Windows Smart Card API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627646(v=vs.85).aspx) which requires [Windows SDK 8.1](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk). Official installation website says:

> You can use the Windows SDK, along with your chosen development
>   environment, to write Windows Store apps and desktop apps for Windows
>   8.1 as well as Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2, and Windows Server 2008

I installed Windows SDK for Windows 8.1 and have got my code compiled successfully:

```
public class WindowsSmartcardManager : ISmartcardManager
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, SmartCardReader> readers;
    private bool paused;

    private int remainingDevicesToBeIdentified = -1;

    public WindowsSmartcardManager()
    {
        readers = new Dictionary<string, SmartCardReader>();

        // First we get the device selector for smart card readers using
        // the static GetDeviceSelector method of the SmartCardReader
        // class.  The selector is a string which describes a class of
        // devices to query for, and is used as the argument to
        // DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync.  GetDeviceSelector is
        // overloaded so that you can provide a SmartCardReaderKind
        // to specify if you are only interested in a particular type
        // of card/reader (e.g. TPM virtual smart card.)  In this case
        // we will list all cards and readers.
        string selector = SmartCardReader.GetDeviceSelector();
        var findAllAsync = DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
        findAllAsync.Completed += FindAllReadersCompleted;
    }
...
```

However, when I try to run my unit tests for the `WindowsSmartCardManager` class, I have got the following error:

[image: error]

The inner exception says "Operation is not supported on this platform":
[image: inner exception]

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 3 on Windows 7, 64-bit, Service Pack 1.

How can I use Windows Smart Card API on Windows 7?

Comment: Have you tried to run in on Windows 10? Cause documentation for the SmartCardReader class clearly says it is Device family: Windows 10 (introduced v10.0.10240.0)

Comment: I must use Windows 7 as a contractual term.

Comment: Well, then you can't use APIs that are not available on Windows 7, right? In such situation I would probably use Win32 smartcard API via P/Invoke.

Comment: But the SDK's documentation stated that it would work in Windows 7.

Comment: No, it didn't. See documentation for the specific API you are after: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.smartcards.smartcardreader - it clearly says that it was introduced in Windows 10. Moreover, whenever you see "UWP" - my understanding is all of it is Windows 10 only.

Comment: @Believe2014 Did you found the answer? I can't find the library either.